# Returning a stream from Swagger generated c# server

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, stream, swagger

Swagger has generated a server from an API with a method like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("SomeRoute")]
    [SwaggerOperation("GetFile")]
    [SwaggerResponse(200, type: typeof(System.IO.Stream))]
    public virtual IActionResult GetFile()
    {
        string exampleJson = null;
        string text = "This could be the contents of a file";

        exampleJson = text;
        var example = exampleJson != null
        ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.IO.Stream>(exampleJson)
        : default(System.IO.Stream);
        return new ObjectResult(example);
    }
```

If I replace "This could be the contents of a file" with lines of code such as:

```
var stream = new FileStream(@".\Files\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var requestBody = new StreamReader(stream,Encoding.ASCII,true).ReadToEnd();
```

I get a JsonConvert exception saying "invalid characters". What is the correct way to return a stream from swagger generated code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
    var stream = new FileStream(@".\Files\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII, true);

    return new ObjectResult(reader.BaseStream);
```